# iOS: Going back to previous screen always waits until scroll finishes

Tags: ios, segue, transition

Anytime we press the back button while the current view is scrolling, we see that the button press was received (the color of the text in the back button changes) but the transition will not take place until the view finishes scrolling. This happens in every view controller of our app and it didn't function this way until recently. We don't know what we possibly could have changed to cause this problem and have been unable to find any global setting that would force this type of behavior. What is going on here?

Comment: Can you post some of your code? I'm thinking that you have an animation or some kind of blocking action running in cellForRowAtIndexPath that is preventing the main UI thread from processing your back button.

Comment: @DanLoughney We see this in both controllers that have table views as well as just a page with a scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Check adding your UI changes to the main queue, that would be:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //UI changes
});
```

Comment: In the view controller that I'm testing all content has been downloaded and the view updated before I click the back button. No UI changes are happening at the time of clicking back.